# Программирование под Android, На чем писать и где?

Tags: android, ide

Нужно для дипломного проекта.
Яву я не знаю, C# встречал, С++ знаю более менее. И хватит ли бесплатного Xamarin, чтобы удобно написать программу с интерфейсом и работой с бд?

Comment: Что касается среды от Xamarin - в бесплатном и легальном варианте у нее чересчур драконовские ограничения на размер проекта. Говорят, что бесплатная версия отказывается компилировать даже некоторые примеры, поставляемые вместе с IDE из-за того, что они превышают этот предельный размер. Хотя, думаю, использование крякнутой версии  исключительно для учебных целей вряд ли можно назвать ужасным преступлением

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Среды: Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA, Android Studio.
2) С C++ писать только с использованием ndk можно. Интерфейс там вряд ли получится сделать нормальный.

Так что, изучайте Java и Android SDK и вперёд.

Comment: А такие штуки как RadStudio(Delphi и С++) и Xamarin(С#)? Я к Java никогда не притрагивался, боюсь что уйдет много время на его изучение.

Comment: @leporel, не уйдёт много времени на изучение. RadStudio не советую трогать - это тихий ужас.

Comment: @leporel, если у вас нет проблем с логикой и хорошо обучаетесь - достаточно проштудировать книгу,просто прочесть, чтобы понять что к чему и уменьшить область "я не знаю, что я не знаю" и перевести в область "я знаю, чего я не знаю". На это уйдет недели 2е. Потом практика уже на примере вашего диплома. Не так страшен черт )) Конечно писать полностью профессиональные программы не получится сразу, но мне хватило 2х недель чтобы начать писать программы под Андроид. Кривые,но рабочие. и каждый день смотрю на вчерашний код и понимаю что бред писал, рабочий но бред, исправляю, развиваюсь. УЧИТЕ JAVA

Answer (score 4):

Поставьте бесплатную android studio и пишите

Answer (score 1):

Лучше JAVA + IntellJ IDEA 12, android studio еще слишком не стабильна, хоть и выглядит приятно

Comment: для диплома ему сойдет